# What programming language should I learn to do this?

Tags: programming-languages

So I'm planning to make a web-based console-like thing. It's like, there will be buttons, and when a specific button was clicked, it will create a *.txt* file and write something in it. I wonder what language should I learn that can make a file and edit it like I said. Thanks!

//Edit:

Sorry if I kinda broke the rules. I'm really new here. And by the way, I forgot to tell that I already know a bit of HTML, CSS, and JS, so the UI will not be a problem, all I need is the language that can make and edit a file ( a .txt file to be specific )

Comment: There are many possible alternatives, you could learn some Python and just a bit of javascript since it's web based. Buy a nice book (don't follow a lousy tutorial, you are a beginner, you need a book) and see how it goes.

Comment: This question will likely be closed and eventually deleted, as it doesn't really fit into our Q&A style here which also requires a programming scope. I've answered just to give you some basic advice really.

Comment: @James, Sorry, I'm new here. This is my first question to be exact xD I'm reading the rules/guidelines now :) And by the way, thanks for that answer! I'll start learning PHP now

Comment: The Stack sites are a bit of a learning curve, as they are slightly different to most other sites, especially forums. So it's worth a bit of a read first. It's definitely worth it, as asking a *good* question will get you some good advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on a lot of parameters which you haven't given, and in fact probably don't even know yourself given what you were asking.

Before you even start with a programming language, you need to know HTML and CSS if you are making a website, as any website needs these and a programming language adds functionality which still needs the website structure and design itself.

HTML/CSS usually doesn't take too long to grasp the basics - depending on your current knowledge and learning abilities etc.
Many guides and tutorials out there for this.

Try to avoid "w3schools" for your learning reference. 
Stick to Stack Overflow and more well linked to guides from Stack Overflow.
There's a lot of bad advice out there and it's harder to unlearn something than it is to just learn best way from the outset.

*As for programming language.*
There are many languages we could recommend, but as they (mostly) each have a specific scenario to be used in, and as you are asking "which language", then you obviously do not have a specific scenario.

As such, and these are arguable points, but given your current position/knowledge, I would suggest starting to learn PHP.

PHP is the most commonly used, and can be used with MySQL (database) quite easily. "Popular" doesn't make it the best, but given it's easy enough to learn, easy enough and free to setup a development area where you can learn and practice, and there are millions of PHP/MySQL guides, tutorials, samples, etc, it is probably the best choice for you.

There are arguable points to what I just wrote, so please don't take it as *concrete fact*, it's just advice.

You need to start by learning how to setup a PHP server so you can write PHP, and for that you will need Apache. You can read many guides and tutorials already out there for this, even good advice found on this site if you search.

Once you can write PHP, learn the very basics, and don't progress until you are very familiar with it. Then once you know the basics, you should write a project/website which you do not care about and won't use (because it won't "likely" be good enough or secure enough to be made live).
Do things such as making it have a login and user area options, which will teach you security with PHP database code, and other things.

Then once you've done that, you can work on something which you *might* make live.

Just make sure you read enough about security, and best practices with whatever you are learning, and "separation of concerns". And do this ***from the start.***
Otherwise you'll be down the road with a handful of code which is hard to work with and likely terrible/unsecure/etc.

---

You are at very beginner level, and you have a long way to go. If you want to succeed in this, and I cannot stress this enough, you will for the first weeks/months do 50 times more reading than you will writing or coding.

You must read. Browse through HTML and CSS questions here on stack, and read basic guides "introduction to" are things you want to learn first.
Then once you can make basic HTML/CSS websites, *then* you need a programming language.

Again, make sure it's a good guide or you'll just make things hard for yourself learning bad practices.